# ClientID Must Be Provided

Tags: php, quickbooks

I'm attempting to add a new bill using the quickbooks API, and I have downloaded the [source code](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QBOConceptsTutorial-PHP/blob/master/PayBill.php) and have filled out the $dataservice array. It looks like :

```
    $dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
        'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
        'ClientID' => $config[CLIENTID],
        'ClientSecret' =>  $config[CLIENTSECRET],
        'RedirectURI' => $config['https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl'],
        'scope' => $config['com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting'],
        'baseUrl' => "production"
    ));
```

With CLIENTID and CLIENTSECRET obviously being the real keys that are generated from my Intuit Developer Account. When I run the php file by going directly to it I get two errors

```
Fatal error: Uncaught QuickBooksOnline\API\Exception\SdkException: [0]: 'ClientID' must be provided in C:\wamp64\www\Bill\vendor\quickbooks\v3-php-sdk\src\Core\ServiceContext.php on line 205
```

and

```
QuickBooksOnline\API\Exception\SdkException: 'ClientID' must be provided in OAuth2. in C:\wamp64\www\Bill\vendor\quickbooks\v3-php-sdk\src\Core\ServiceContext.php on line 205
```

But as seen above I have set the ClientID. Is there a different way I'm supposed to Access the php file, or is there another config file that should have ClientID set?
Not sure if it's necessary info but I installed the Quickbooks SDK with Composer

Comment: Are you _100% sure_ you actually filled in the `ClientID`? I bet it's not filled in/you're using something that isn't actually defined.

Comment: It's defined just like I posted in the $config array above. Except 'CLIENTID' is my actual ClientID